# Checking non linear effects in LASSO regression

Tags: lasso, nonlinear-regression, glmnet

This might be a weird question and I understand that LASSO is mainly using as a variable selection method.

But I want to know that is it possible to check non-linear effects of a LASSO logistic regression model .

In GLM setting , we usually do this by fitting two uni variate models. First model with linear effects and the second model with non linear effects . Then chi square test can be used to check whether the non linear effects are significant.

I tried to do the same thing using glmnet package as follows,

My  multiple Lasso logistic regression model :

```
y <- Smarket$Direction
x <- model.matrix(Direction ~ Lag1 + Lag2 + Lag3 + Lag4 + Volume, Smarket)[, -1]

lasso.mod <- glmnet(x,y, alpha = 1, lambda = 0.002,family='binomial')

lasso.mod$beta
5 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                 s0
Lag1   -0.065571799
Lag2   -0.035641706
Lag3    0.003564320
Lag4    0.001534812
Volume  0.110035335
```

Then i tried to check non linear effects for each predictor , by first fitting a uni variate LASSO regression model

```
y <- Smarket$Direction
x1<- model.matrix(Direction ~ Lag1 , Smarket) 
lasso.mod1 <- glmnet(x1,y, alpha = 1, lambda = 0.002,family='binomial')
lasso.mod1$beta
2 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
                     s0
(Intercept)  .         
Lag1        -0.06312753
```

**After this , is there way to fit univariate lasso model with non linear effects ? Also after fitting that what test can we used to check the non linear effects (can we use chi square test ?) ?**

Thank you

Comment: As far as LASSO is concerned, the idea is mainly to use predictions on a test set / CV to check which model performs better. And if it performs better you can conclude that it probably better describes the data.

Comment: @user2974951 Thank you for comment.  What do you mean by "performs better" ? Does it mean the model with lowest cross validation error ?

Comment: The model which maximizes / minimizes your accuracy metric, such as accuracy, misclassification, F1, and so on. Or a scoring rule.

Comment: what is a univariate LASSO regression? Do you fit the least squares model with LASSO and a single covariate??

Answer (score 1):

One package you may try is spikeSlabGAM. It's not fast, but it will build nonlinear models and perform selection. To directly answer your question, LASSO is a linear method, but you could make nonlinear terms through transformation (e.g. Lag1^2) and see if they stay in the model.